# How do i move or exctract number portions from a cell to another in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to move numbers from one cell to another, or in some way extract numbers from one cell to another, with the number being removed from its previous cell.

Picture of how i want the data to be presented

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=--CONCAT(IFERROR(--MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),""))
```

Or, in case you have values like `Test1 Test2 123456`:

```
=--LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),FILTER(a,ISNUMBER(--a)))
```

---

**EDIT:** The question is not solely about moving numbers but about presenting input without the number and the number seperately. Therefor try:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=LET(a,TEXTSPLIT(A1," "),HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(" ",,FILTER(a,ISERROR(--a))),--FILTER(a,ISNUMBER(--a))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! but i do not get the answer i want from this formula. Also i do not want the results in B to appear in A, B should onle contain the letters

Comment: Correction; numbers* not letters - b should only contain numbers!

Comment: Right I see what you mean. I'll edit the answer

Comment: Oki am i doing thi completly wrong i added your formul =LET(a;TEXTSPLIT(A2;" ");HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(" ";;FILTER(a;ISERROR(--a)));--FILTER(a;ISNUMBER(--a))))) to F2 in my worksheet an got a #NAME?-error

Comment: @eastafricancoder What version of Excel.  The formula provided requires Excel 365

Comment: @RonRosenfeld excuse my late reply. I have the Microsoft 365 excel version MSO (16.0.14326.21092) - so, this should not be the problem?

Comment: @eastafricancoder The formula works OK here. I suspect your version may not have the latest functions yet -- possibly `HSTACK`.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to use `FILTERXML()` to extract numeric nodes.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[number()=.]"))
```

- Here `"<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>"` will construct a valid xml string.
- `FILTERXML()` will process that xml string and `xPath` parameter `//s[number()=.]` will return only numeric nodes.

To know more about `FILTERXML()` read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747) by @JvdV.

[image]

Comment: This will stay a nice way to split text. But since TEXTSPLIT is introduced I think we'll be using that more often. Also because it's easier to write. The regex handling is definitely useful though. Too bad it's only useful for Windows environment.

Comment: @P.b That is limitation of `FILTERXML()` but in some case it is really nice.